# Table View not showing up as expected

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm pretty new to Xcode and I'm learning. I'm trying to make a test app. I can't get it to show up in the app like I set it in my storyboard?

[image: This shows my problem.]

Comment: Prototype cells and static cells are different. Learn more about `UITableView`'s structure [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview).

Comment: Add your code so we can help u

Comment: TableViews are intended to be backed programmatically by a datasource.  Short story: the view controller needs to implement the table view datasource and delegate protocols, and in the story board you need the table view to be connected to the view controller as it's data source and delegate (sorta like the IBOutlets). I hate RTFM answers, but honestly, I'd suggest searching for a UITableieView tutorial. (Ray Wenderlich is typically pretty good)

Comment: I don't have any code for it yet. Was just playing around with it. I'll be sure to check it out on YouTube. I just thought it was going to show like I made it look in the editor. Sorry I'm such a noob.

Comment: @AppleTestBoy how do you expect it to work without code!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a UITableViewController and assign it to your tableView. And FYI in Xcode you design one cell only if you are using dynamic cells and the population of the cells will all happen inside your UITableViewController (hence the name PrototypeCell)